# Run Simpletest tests on Jenkins

Tags: testing, deployment

I am trying to run a group of tests(Simpletest) for my custom modules through Jenkins.

1. Firstly I tried `drush test-run (...)` which has been removed from drush.
2. Then I tried `php scripts/run-tests.sh --xml logs_tests [GROUP_NAME]`, but for every test class it returns `/usr/bin/daemon: unrecognized option '--url'`. I haven't defined any URL, maybe is something Simpletest specific.
3. Finally, I created a fairly simple Phing task `<exec command="php scripts/run-tests.sh --xml logs_tests ${group_name}" error="build_error"/>` only to get the response `Unknown argument: --url`, from Phing this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue you're mentioning in #2, getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/daemon: unrecognized option '--url'
```

## Solution

I found that the solution to this is specifying the PHP binary to `scripts/run-tests.sh` as such:

```
php scripts/run-tests.sh --php /usr/bin/php --url http://127.0.0.1
```

## Explanation

This is due to the way that jenkins starts programs, something like:

```
daemon program --parameters...
```

But run-tests.sh (lines 256-258) pulls the command that was run (falsely pulling `daemon php --parameters`) and thinks that the php binary is `daemon`.

The culprit code is:

```
 elseif ($php_env = getenv('_')) {
    // '_' is an environment variable set by the shell. It contains the command that was executed.
    $php = $php_env;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have tried everything except to supply the URL.

You must supply a --url argument to execute simpletest. This is what I use, where "IAS" is the test group I have selected to execute:

```
php scripts/run-tests.sh --url http://localhost/drupal7 --concurrency 4 IAS
```

It follows that you must have a Drupal install to do this.